# How to Specify Network Security Group When Creating NIC In Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk

Right now, I am creating a NIC to be used by a VM on Azure but I need the VM to allow port 80. To do so, I need to use a network security group but I don't know how to specify that when I create the NIC for my VM. Here is my current code: `nicParams = {
    'location': LOCATION,
    'ip_configurations': [{
        'name': VM_NAME + "-ipconfig",
        'public_ip_address': publicIP,
        'subnet': {
            'id': subnetInfo.id
        }
    }],
}
nicCreationResult = network_client.network_interfaces.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME + "-nic", nicParams)`

What should I add into the nicParams to specify the network security group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the ID of your NSG and reference it in your NIC parameters at the first level of the vNIC:

```
nicParams = {
    'location': LOCATION,
    'ip_configurations': [{
        'name': VM_NAME + "-ipconfig",
        'public_ip_address': publicIP,
        'subnet': {
            'id': subnetInfo.id
        }
    }],
    'network_security_group': {
        'id': '<NSG-ID-HERE>'
    }
}
nicCreationResult = network_client.network_interfaces.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME + "-nic", nicParams)
```

If network_security_group doesn't work, try networkSecurityGroup.

Comment: this solution saved my day :) ,

Comment: just some extra info - nsg id should look like this;  `/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<your-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/<your-nsg-name>`